# Ajax for changing displayed image in php

Tags: php, ajax

Currently, if no images have been clicked, I get my selected image like this and it's also what's shown on first page load.

```
$pictures = Picture::getPictures($album->getId());
$selectedPicture = $pictures[0];
```

It selects the first picture and display it like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $selectedPicture->getOriginalFilePath($user->getId()); ?>" >
```

I am trying to change the selected image when a user clicks on a different thumbnail because this is just one of many images of an album.

Attempt with a ajax, I'm not really experienced with it so I couldn't get it to work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function Func() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "RefreshImage.php",
                    success: function (json) {}, error: function () {}
                })
            }
 </script>
```

Then the php portion also has something like to create the thumbnails so that a user can clicks on one, it displays the image. But I'm not sure how to do that.

```
foreach ($pictures as $pic) {
    $output.= "<a href='" . $pic->getOriginalFilePath($user->getId()) . "'> <img style='width:120px;height:120px' "
            . "src='" . $pic->getThumbnailFilePath($user->getId()) . "'"
            . "name='" . $pic->getFileName() . "' "
            . "onClick='Func'></a>";
}
```

RefreshImage.php content

```
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['user'];

//$albums = Album::getAlbums($user->getId());

if (isset($_POST["chosenAlbid"])) {

    $album_id = $_POST["chosenAlbid"];
    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
    $album = Album::getAlbumById($user->getId(), $album_id);
    $pictures = Picture::getPictures($album->getId());
    $selectedPicture = $pictures[1];
}
?>

<div id="imagecontainer">
    <div>
        <p style="float: left;"><img style="width:500px;height:400px" src="<?php echo $selectedPicture->getOriginalFilePath($user->getId()); ?>" ></p>
        <p><span>
                <h4>  Description</h4>
            </span><?php echo $selectedPicture->getDescription() ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your RefreshImage.php should return url new image and then in success fnc you set image path as $('img').attr('src', newUrlImage);

Comment: but how can I set the url?

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite your function into jQuery it will be more easy.

From this

```
function Func() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "RefreshImage.php",
    success: function (json) {}, error: function () {}
  })
}
```

To jQuery

```
$('a[data-refresh-img]').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // block ahref redirect
   $('#imagecontainer img').attr('src', $(this).attr('href')); // replace image
);
```

Then activate function add `data-refresh-img` attribute on `a tag`.
And all will work for you.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/daremachine/zneg53u1/7/)

** **UPDATE** **
If you need replace any data with image you can do this

```
<a data-refresh-img href="original_img_path">
  <img
    title="picture one"
    src="thumbnail_img_path" height=50>
  <span style="display: none"><?php echo $selectedPicture->getDescription() ?> AAA</span>
</a>
```

And change function to

```
$('a[data-refresh-img]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // block ahref redirect    
  $('#imagecontainer img').attr('src', $(this).attr('href')); // replace image   
  $('#imagecontainer img').attr('title', $(this).find('img').attr('title')); // replace title    
  $('#imagecontainer span[data-description]').html($(this).find('span').html()); // replace description 
});
```

[JSFIDDLE 2](https://jsfiddle.net/daremachine/zneg53u1/25/)

Comment: add `data-refresh-img` as the href instead? and also `src` would be my `refreshimage.php` right

Comment: @answerSeeker ah sorry i will update in your case but i dont know where you show big image

Comment: the image is in a div called `imagecontainer`

Comment: this should work if you click on image thumbnail you will show big image from a href path in imagecontainer.

Comment: OK thanks, how to I make the refreshimage.php work? I will update the question on what I have so far in it

Comment: @answerSeeker you ask for two question. First how you can change image from thumbnail click to imagecontainer and second how you can change image with random ajax?

Comment: Sorry if you think they're different. I'm just trying to display the selected picture as in the picture that was clicked in a div called imagecontainer, I tried your approach but it still just opens the image original path when I click on it and left the current page.

Comment: should I remove image source? Because it is still redirecting

Comment: remove your onclick fnc, remove data-refresh-img from img and add it to a like <a data-refresh-img href="original-img...and update js from this updated fnc. I tested it in jsfiddle and it work.

Comment: tried that and same thing. It is redirecting to a page with the fullsize image

Comment: check jsfiddle demo and check if your jquery is loaded. I don't see any problem.

Comment: Thanks, it works now but image attributes like description aren't displayed because only the image changed. Oh well, thanks anyways.

Comment: I updated again but next time you clarify your question better please.